# require_once(../../path/to/script.php) failed to open stream permission denied

Tags: php, linux, security, file-permissions

See an example here: http://mattpotts.com/portal/

I put an `includeme.htm` in each directory on the required path to find the point of failure. It works fine on my local machine (windows) with the same directory structure but fails on my remote (linux) server.

Directory structure:

```
+-firefli/                 drwx--x--x
  +-private_html/          drwx------
    +-foo/                 drwxr-xr-x
    +-bar/                 drwxr-xr-x
    +-portal/              drwxr-wr-w
  +-public_html/           drwxr-wr-w
    +-foo/                 drwxr-wr-w
    +-portal/              drwxr-wr-w
```

The permissions confirm that it's the `private_html` directory causing the trouble. Hopefully you can see the purpose of the directory structure, I don't know if it's a common way of doing things but it works for me. Well, until now.

I've gone a very long way around asking it but my question is simply this: is there anything wrong with setting `private_html` to be `drwxr-xr-x`? Given that I do not want it to be accessible via the web. But the permissions shouldn't do that should they? Because it's apache making the `public_html` directory accessible via http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have set up your `DocumentRoot` correctly to point to `public_html`, it won't be accessible from the web, no matter what permissions you put on it.

The Private HTMl is not accessible from the web without you putting in a .htaccess file that would redirect it. If you don't know what that means/how to do that, you are safe.

You should be fine setting these permissions to whatever your script needs.

Comment: who will it be accessible to? if i change it from drwx------ to drwxr-xr-x?

Comment: It won't be accessible via web. But it will be accessible to other FTP users. (This is, of course, assuming no bad htaccess files are present).

Comment: Why would you want to make it accessible from public_html?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x would be all permissions to user and read and execute to group and world

Comment: @chacha102 that's fine - it's a trusted group

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to block out web users with folder/file permissions on private_html, as it's outside the web root. As you say, web users can only get to stuff in public_html

For future debugging speed, if you have a relative web path you can convert it to a real path using realpath:

```
$path = realpath('../../private_html');
// $path is now /public_html/foo/private.html or whatever
```

Comment: The permissions on private_html are just whatever they came as. I've not touched them. Yet...

Answer (score 0):

what are the `user:group` for `private_html`? The web server needs to be either a member of the group or the owner of the file. In order to read the directory contents the dirctory needs to have the `execute` permission for the webserver to open it. Essentially they should have the same `user:group` as `public_html`. You just want to disallow the `write` permission. tot he webserver. If you have set your document root to `public_html` `private_html` is not accessible via the web no matter what the permissions. Also, i always use `realpath` on the path arguments to and file operation.